# Pageshow event not happening in Backbone with JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, jqplot

I am trying to convert a JQuery Mobile app over to Backbone. I am using the HTML5/Backbone/Jquery Mobile template that comes with Netbeans. Everything is going fine except 'pageshow' event is not firing when backbone renders the page. The original is a multi page template. The backbone version is identical except the page is delivered dynamically.

The page contains a canvas that I use to display a Jqplot chart. Page renders fine but the chart is never created because 'pageshow' event which creates the chart never happens.

I have the pageshow script at the bottom of the body.

```
        <!-- Draw chart -->
<script>
$('#page2').on('pageshow', function() {
    console.log("Pageshow triggered");
    $.jqplot('chart1',  [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]],  {
      axesDefaults: {
        labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
      },
      axes: {
        xaxis: {
          label: " ",
          pad: 0
        },
        yaxis: {
          label: " ",
          pad: 0
        }
      }
    }).replot({clear: true, resetAxes:true});       

});           
</script>
```

Hope you can help.

Paul

Comment: `$(document).on('pageshow', '#page2', function() {` delegate event.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Event still not occurring. The Jquery Mobile router is disabled when using backbone. What did work though is that I put the code in a function and used a button on the page to run it after the page had loaded. Now to figure out where is the best place to put the function call so that it runs after everything has loaded. Putting it after the backbone render doesn't work.

Comment: I just tried the Backbone after render solution at: http://fahad19.tumblr.com/post/28158699664/afterrender-callback-in-backbone-js-views Unfortunately this didn't work either. Still Jqplot hasn't finished loading.